# force recompile of application.js during testing a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, sprockets

I am testing a gem. So I have a setup like this:

spec ->
  test_app ->
    app -> 
      etc...
  spec_helper.rb
  etc ...

The problem is that in order to test the gem, I need to use selenium/capybara and I need to change things in application.js

But no matter what I do I cannot get a new version of application.js to compile and download.

For example between tests, I stop the test (using binding.pry) go in and physically update test_app/app/assets/javascripts/application.js but it still serves the previous version of application.js.

I have even tried deleting tmp/cache/* and still it serves the previous version.

I have hardcoded the reference to application.js in the test HTML file, and put a TS on the query string, and STILL it downloads the previous version...

HOW CAN I KILL THE CURRENT compiled version of application.js, and force it to regenerate?

Comment: I asked a similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38861128/invalidate-sprockets-cache-during-rspec-automated-test.  Some ideas might pop up there.