# Invalidate Sprockets cache during RSpec automated test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, sprockets

In my Rails application, I have a .js.erb file that has a variable which gets dynamically set based on some Ruby code.

```js
var myTimer = <%= MyApp.config.timeout_time * 1000 %>;
```

The app works fine, but I'm having a problem in some automated tests.  The problem occurs in an RSpec feature test that works with this JavaScript.  My spec file has a number of tests that change the ruby `MyApp.config.timeout_time` time on the fly to test out different scenarios.  In my spec file, the first example passes, and the rest fail.

I finally realized this is happening because `myTimer` never gets updated on the JavaScript side.  When the first test runs, the JavaScript gets compiled using the current value as it's set in Ruby.  When I change the Ruby timer for the second test, RSpec is still using the previous value in the JavaScript.

**Is there a way to tell Sprockets/Rails to invalidate a file or a part of the cache so the JavaScript will get rebuilt?**  I don't want to turn off caching in general, I just need a way to invalidate application.js on a per-test basis when needed.

I may be able to "touch" one of the JavaScript files on the file system to make sprockets think the file has been changed, but I don't really want to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to do what you asked. But you could consider setting `myTimer` to the value you want it to be in the feature specs that need it to be a specific value.

Assuming you're using Capybara, you can run Javascript in a feature spec with

```
page.execute_script('// some Javascript')
```

You might need to rearrange your Javascript a bit first to put `myTimer` somewhere where a script can change it.

Comment: Thank you, this is a great idea.  I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Did you have any luck?

Comment: I'm not sure yet.  I got redirected to support some other issues and haven't had a chance to try this out yet.  I'll update once I know more.

Comment: I was finally able to come back to the project and try this out.  Your suggestion worked great.  Thank you!